# Javascript activate pop up after form validation

Tags: javascript, validation, popup

I want to have a popup appear after a html form has been validated using the form's submit button. I wrote some JavaScript and the form get validated, but the pop-up does not appear, or at least it appears, but immediately disappears. Below is the html and JavaScript -- First, the fields in the form are validated, and if true, the pop-up is activated.:

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="req_form" style="margin-top:40px">
            <form name="req_book">
                <table width= "450px">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="book_title">Book Title</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="book_title" maxlength="175" size="50" required>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="author">Full author's name</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="author" maxlength="225" size="50" required>
                        </td>                       
                    </tr>                   
                </table>
           <hr>
            <p>Requested by:</p>
                <table width= "450px">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="first_name">First name </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="175" size="50" required>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="last_name">Last name</label>
                        </td>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" id="popupLink" value="Submit"> 
                        </td>                       
                    </tr>                    
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>

        <!-- POPUP BOX -->
        <div id="popupBox" class="popup">
            <!-- Popup content -->
            <div class="popup-content">
                <div class="popup-head">
                    <span class="close">close</span>
                    <h2>Your request for {BOOK_TITLE} has been processed.</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="popup-main">
                    <p>Succes!</p>
                    <p>Your request has been submitted to our library.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="popup-foot">
                    <p><a href="printer_version.html" target="_blank">click here </a>for a printable version on-screen (opens in new tab)</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('popupLink');

function popUp() {
   var popup = document.getElementById('popupBox');

   // get the close action element
   var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

   popup.style.display = "block";

   // close the Popup once close element is clicked
   close.onclick = function() {
       popup.style.display = "none";
   }

   // close the Popup when user clicks outside of the box
   window.onclick = function(event) {
       if (event.target == popup) {
           popup.style.display = "none";
       }        
   }
}

btn.addEventListener('click',function validateForm() {
     var isValid = true;
     var htmlFormFieldTitle = document.forms["req_book"]["book_title"].value;
     var htmlFormFieldAuthor = document.forms["req_book"]["author"].value;
     var htmlFormFieldFirst_name = document.forms["req_book"]["first_name"].value;
     var htmlFormFieldLast_name = document.forms["req_book"]["last_name"].value;

     if (htmlFormFieldTitle == "" && htmlFormFieldAuthor =="" && htmlFormFieldFirst_name =="" && htmlFormFieldLast_name =="") {
           alert('some fields are mandatory')
            isValid= false;
                    }
      if (isValid = True){
        popUp();
        }
     });
```

Why is my pop-up window disappearing immediately and how can I fix this?
A test page with just the popup code does work. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reload the page when you click on the button.
To prevent this, add `e.preventDefault()` add the beginning of your callback function.

```
  btn.addEventListener('click',function validateForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ...
  });
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 1):

I have found some issues:

1 - When there is a form and a button with the type "submit" in, the markup language attempts to post after the button click by including the data in url.

```
URL Before Click: https://foobar.com/index.html
URL After Click: https://foobar.com/index.html?book_title=a&author=a&first_name=a&last_name=a
```

So, how to prevent that?

You can call preventDefault mehod by event parameter:

```
btn.addEventListener('click',function validateForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ...
});
```

or you can also add javascript void(0) function action as form attribute:

```
<form name="req_book" action="javascript:void(0)">
<!-- ... -->
</form>
```

2 - The last_name input is missing, you need to add that:

```
<td>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="175" size="50" required/>
</td>
```

3 - Javascript is case-sensitive, so lets fix it:

```
btn.addEventListener('click',function validateForm() {
    // ...
    if (isValid == true) {
        popUp();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Phil said, you have three errors in your code. You forgot to include an HMTL input element for `last_name` and you have two typos in your comparison. Correct this:

```
if (isValid = True){
    popUp();
}
```

to this:

```
if (isValid == true){
    popUp();
}
```

The JavaScript `true` value is always lowercase. Additionally, a single `=` is used for assignments, not comparisons.

You can see JavaScript errors yourself by opening the console of your web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Hay dear,
When you using submit button with form, when you click submit button it will submit the form. So when submiting the form it must call the action link. But if it has not action link page is going to reload.

You can do two methods, 
01. For avoid reload page you can use,

```
e.preventDefault()
```

Inside your btn. Click function.

Or

02 For avoud reload page you can use
Your button type as button. So change button type from submit to button. Because of you are using button click method.

Change :

```
<input type="submit" />

       To

<input type="button"  />
```

> you can use button type when you capture the click event only. If you are using submit event you have to use submit type as input type.

You can do severel things like that.